# Is "ice point" the same as "freezing point"?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

I am using an old book and they almost use both terms interchangeably sometimes. Do they mean the same thing? Similiarly for "steam point" and "boiling point"

Comment: Could you gives us a few sample sentences?

Comment: Sounds like it, but I've never heard "ice point" or "steam point" used before.

Comment: I've heard the term 'ice point' used and I think this is an interesting question.  Certainly, and ice phase is different from 'freezing' - the latter which is transitional and regionally-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ice point is the freezing point of water.

Freezing point is the point where liquid turns to solid.

The difference is that in the case of ice point is substance is always water.

(Note that there is a slight discrepancy of 0.01 K between the triple point of water, melting point, freezing point and/or ice point. And technically, Ice point is the point where water and Ice are in equillibrium.)

See e.g. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freezing+point, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ice+point.